# How can I add an attribute to a direct link menu item?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, accessibility

I would like, ideally in the php file of a menu override, to add `role="menu-item"` i.e. direct links to another location, in a Joomla 3x (and 4x) menu.

Is this possible, or do I need to use JavaScript? (No jQuery, please).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much experimentation I'm pretty sure it's not possible to achieve this without Javascript, but I did manage it this way:

I added this code to the menu's main php file (about line 53 in the default.php override):

```
    if ($item!=parent)
    {
        $class .= ' single';
    }
```

Then in the template.js added this:

```
    let single = [...document.querySelectorAll('li > a')];
    [].forEach.call(single, function(sg) {
    sg.setAttribute("role", "menuitem");
    })
    let singleb = [...document.querySelectorAll('li.single > button > a')];
    [].forEach.call(singleb, function(sgb) {
    sgb.setAttribute("role", "menuitem");
    })
```

I'm using buttons in my navigation but if you're not you can leave out the second half of this code.